# What does " :: " mean in my connections ? ("TCP local address :: port 49157")

Tags: windows, ip-address

It says:

> TCP local address  :: port 49157
>   remote port N/A etc.
>   status listen

There are several connections listed under `svchost.exe`, `services.exe`, `Issas.exe`, `wininit.exe`, `system`. I have no clue what that is telling me. Is it some kind of stealth Trojan type port to "listen"?

Answer (score 6):

:: is the indicator for an IPv6 address equivalent to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.

So, it's a port listening on any local configured IPv6 address.